# Using Instagram API to make users populate images into my Django application directly from Instagram Pictures

Tags: django, instagram, instagram-api

**My use case or what I want to do is:**

1. - Users click a Upload button,
   - it authenticates user,
   - its shows Instagram images,
   - users select, and
   - user click upload button to upload images or videos (media) from
     Instagram directly into my django app.

**What I have done is:**

- Instagram integration:

> `pip install python-instagram`

- views.py:

> ```
> @login_required()
> def instagram_pictures(request, template='dashboard/add-instagram-pictures.html'):
>     user = request.user
>     gallery = []
>     gallery = Gallery.objects.filter(service_provider=user.service_provider_profile)
>     context = {'gallery': gallery}
>     return render(request, template, context)
>
> @login_required()
> def add_instagram_pictures(request, template='dashboard/add-instagram-pictures.html'):
>     access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" # Dont know how this gets factored in for any user
>     client_secret = settings.SECRET_ID
>     api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
>     recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
>     for media in recent_media:
>         print(media.caption.text)
> ```

- template/my-gallery.html:

> ```
> {% extends 'base.html' %}
> {% load static %}
> {% block title %}My Dashboard{% endblock %}
> {% block content %}
>     <div class="page-header" style="background: url({% static 'img/banner1.jpg' %});">
>         <div class="container">
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-md-12">
>                     <h1 class="page-title">My Gallery</h1>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>
>     <div id="content">
>         <div class="container">
>             <div class="row">
>                 {% include '_side_menu.html' %}
>                 <div class="col-md-8 page-content">
>                     <div class="inner-box text-center">
>                         <a href="{% url 'dashboard:add-instagram-pictures' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-success">
>                             <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"> Upload from Instagram</span>
>                         </a>
>                         <ul>
>                         <!-- I will re-write this loop to redefine how images are rendered for the project. Maybe in Carousels-->
>                             {% for p in photos %}
>                                 <li>{{ p.name }}</li>
>                             {% endfor %}
>                         </ul>
>                     </div>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

- template/add-instagram-pictures.html:

> ```
> {% extends 'base.html' %}     
> {% load static %} 
> {% block title %}Add Gallery{% endblock %} 
> {% block content %}
> <div class="page-header" style="background: url({% static 'img/banner1.jpg' %});">
>     <div class="container">
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col-md-12">
>                 <h1 class="page-title">Add Instagram Pictures</h1>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
> <div id="content">
>     <div class="container">
>         <div class="row">
>             {% include '_side_menu.html' %}
>             <div class="col-md-8 page-content">
>                 <div class="inner-box text-center">
>                     <a href="{% url 'dashboard:my-gallery' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-success">
>                         <span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"> Back to Album List</span>
>                     </a>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div> {% endblock %}Add
> ```

- url.py:

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import url, include
> from dashboard.views import dashboard, my_services, add_service, my_gallery, add_gallery, bank_profile, add_bank_profile, add_instagram_pictures
>
>
> def ajax_photo_upload_view(args):
>     pass
>
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     url(r'^$', dashboard, {}, name='home'),
>     url(r'^bank-profile/$', bank_profile, {}, name='bank-profile'),
>     url(r'^add-bank-profile/$', add_bank_profile, name='add-bank-profile'),
>     url(r'^my-services/$', my_services, name='my-services'),
>     url(r'^add-service/$', add_service, name='add-service'),
>     url(r'^add-gallery/$', add_gallery, name='add-gallery'),
>     url(r'^my-gallery/$', my_gallery, name='my-gallery'),
>     url(r'^add-gallery/$', add_instagram_pictures, name='add-instagram-pictures'),
>
> ]
> ```

- settings.py:

> ```
> # instagram settings
>
> CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
> SECRET_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
> ```

How do I go about my use case as I have stated, my solution is in no way closer to what I want to do.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: No @AaronCloud. The library is not maintained. I had to follow what was listed on Instagram API Docs